# Convert a Netlogo list to an R vector

Tags: r, netlogo

I am using BehaviorSpace to run experiments with my Netlogo model and output to file in table format. One of the things I log is the list which contains all selected actions by the agents. I use R for analysis and would like to draw a histogram based on that list. The list is a string in the `csv`-file in Netlogo format `[0 1 2 3 4 5]`. Is there a painless way to convert this to a R vector?

ps: I am aware of the [RNetlogo] library and how it has methods to extract the data into vectors. But it didn't really work for me and I would like to proceed with file output.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way that I think accomplishes what you need in base r. Assuming that your table output looks something like:

[image]

Read that file in however you like, for example with

```
df <- read.csv("example_bspace_output.csv", skip = 6, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, use `lapply` to take each observation in your column of interest, use `gsub` to remove the square brackets and combine `unlist`, `as.numeric`, and `strsplit` to your numeric values (don't use `as.numeric` if you have some string output).

```
vals_list <- lapply(df$xcor_list, function(x){
  y <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x)
  unlist(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(y, " "))), recursive = TRUE)

})

> vals_list
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1]  0.9205049 -0.8386706  0.9876883

[[3]]
[1]  1.841010 -1.677341  1.975377

[[4]]
[1]  2.963065 -2.516012  2.761515

[[5]]
[1]  3.682019 -3.354682  3.950753

[[6]]
[1] -4.193353  4.938442  4.602524
```

Hopefully that'll work, let me know if I need to fix anything.